# Possible combinations of a matrix in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have a data frame as

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(11,12,13,14,15))
```

What I am trying to get is this

```
df
1  11
2  12
3  13
4  14
5  15
2  12
3  13
4  14
5  15
3  13
4  14
5  15
5  15
```

It basically is all the possible combinations of the data frame. I tried combn and expand.grid but they give me all possible combinations, not all possible combinations taken two at a time. I also tried looping it but the subsetting always goes for a toss.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "taken two at a time"?

Comment: I don't think combinations is what you're looking for here. Could you try clarifying. Your example isn't very clear.

Comment: What I want is something like this, set 1 = (a,b,c). All possible subsets of set1 are (a,b,c,b,c,c).

Comment: Could it be that in the example in your question some elements are missing?

Comment: You can do something like:`unlist(lapply(df$x, function(x){ df$y[x:5] } ))`

Comment: You are bound to get answers that do not help due to the oversimplicity of your example. You should design a more complex example that better reflects the typical variation in inputs that you will actually deal with. Does your actual data really have a set of integers in sequential order?

Comment: they are actually a set of 105 coordinates that I am going to make a line to based on some weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can sequence by the pairs with an `sapply` iteration. Then binding the vectors with the index:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(11,12,13,14,15))
s <- seq(length(df$x))
d2 <- unlist(sapply(s, seq, to=max(s)))
cbind.data.frame(x=df$x[d2], y=df$y[d2])
#    x  y
# 1  1 11
# 2  2 12
# 3  3 13
# 4  4 14
# 5  5 15
# 6  2 12
# 7  3 13
# 8  4 14
# 9  5 15
# 10 3 13
# 11 4 14
# 12 5 15
# 13 4 14
# 14 5 15
# 15 5 15
```