# Matrix of combinations of two vectors

Tags: r, combinations

I have two vectors, say:

```
x <- c("b", "p", "t")
y <- c("a", "e", "i")
```

I want to get a Matrix of their possible combinations.

```
df <- cbind(b=c("ba", "be", "bi"), p=c("pa", "pe", "pi"), t=c("ta", "te", "ti"))
rownames(df) <- c("a", "e", "i")
```

I have seen [Possible combinations of a matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229012/possible-combinations-of-a-matrix-in-r) but it doesn't do the trick here.

Also I have tried `CJ(x,y)` with `data.table`,
but still I would need further steps to manipulate 
the data.

Is there a more simple solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
out <- outer(x, y, FUN = paste0)
dimnames(out) <- list(x, y)
```

Comment: Works perfectly...why did I not know that function?

Answer (score 1):

We also may use `expand.grid`

```
matrix(Reduce(paste0, expand.grid(x, y)), 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "ba" "be" "bi"
# [2,] "pa" "pe" "pi"
# [3,] "ta" "te" "ti"
```

Comment: Thx, yes I have used expand.grid, yet it I have to say the outer() is less cumbersome

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi Yes, `outer` is great, there's not just one way to do it.